# Duplicate tags [infringement] and [patent-infringement]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't think there is a relevant difference that can be conveyed to everyone (or enough ppl) using these tags, I'd say they are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Added the synonym, now it needs votes:

https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/patent-infringement/synonyms

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.